# CreateProcessAsUser results in process exit and error 0xc0000142 when the process starts

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess, createprocessasuser

I am creating a simple console application to learn the usage of [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw).

I have followed what little code examples I can find online. I have also completed a similar example application that uses `CreateProcess()` (following more or less [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa)), and that worked fine.

I basically modified that example to use [`LogonUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw), then pass that token to `CreateProcessAsUser()`. I also used [`CreateEnvironmentBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock) to get the environment of the token. Although I'm not sure that's necessary, examples I saw included that step. I printed out the results of `CreateEnvironmentBlock()`, and they are as I expect, including showing that the current user is the one I'm trying to logon as.

My problem: `CreateProcessAsUser()` executes without error, but the child process `whoami.exe` immediately creates a popup saying:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.

[image]

I am launching my application from an administrator command prompt, and through Local Security Policy I have granted administrators and my specific account the User Rights `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` and `SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege`, which I read are required to call `CreateProcessAsUser()`. I am a little uncertain if there is more I need to do to ensure my calling process has these privileges. Do I need to programmatically enable these permissions too?

The logon account `username` below is a normal account. It has the permission to access and execute `whoami.exe` and to logon interactively. I do not believe it requires other permissions (?).

Here is my code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    WCHAR cmd_line[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\whoami.exe";

    HANDLE token = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPVOID proc_env = NULL;
    char username[MAX_PATH] = "username";

    BOOL success = LogonUserA(username, "machine_domain", "password",
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "LogonUser() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    if (token == NULL || token == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "token is bad" << std::endl;
    }

    // Use token to get environment.
    success = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&proc_env, token, FALSE);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateEnvironmentBlock() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(token);
        return 1;
    }
    if (proc_env == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "procenv is null" << std::endl;
    }

    success = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        NULL,   // app name
        cmd_line,    // includes app name.
        NULL,   // proc security attrs
        NULL,   // thread security attrs
        FALSE,   // inherit handles
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, // creation flags
        proc_env,    // env
        L"C:\\",   // current dir
        &si,    // startupinfo
        &pi);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateProcessAsUser() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried many other options in `CreationFlags` (eg `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`), and also I have tried setting `STARTUPINFO`'s `lpDesktop` to `"winsta0\\default"`, as suggested in some posts. Everything I tried had the same result, but maybe I'm missing the correct option.

### Edit 1

I made slight edits to ensure `STARTUPINFO`'s std handles were configured with pipes correctly, which included changing `lbInherit` to `TRUE` as required when `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is specified. The below code works for me *if the target user is Administrator*. The pipe outputs the `whoami` results for the target user as expected! (I tried `NULL` `L""` and `L"winsta0\\default"` as lpDesktop and all worked.) However I am getting the same failure as before when the target user is not admin.
I found [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/what-is-up-with-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0000142-error) [articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/how-to-launch-a-process-interactively-from-a-windows-service) suggesting the launched process needs permission to access the desktop `winsta0\default`. Is it possible to grant this permission to a non-admin account? I also see the suggestion to try `CreateProcessWithLogon()` which I will try.

```
int main()
{

    WCHAR cmd_line[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\whoami.exe";

    HANDLE token = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPVOID proc_env = NULL;
    char username[MAX_PATH] = "target_user";

    BOOL success = LogonUserA(username, "domain_local", "password",
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "LogonUser() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    if (token == NULL || token == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "token is bad" << std::endl;
    }

    // Use token to get environment.
    success = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&proc_env, token, FALSE);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateEnvironmentBlock() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(token);
        return 1;
    }
    if (proc_env == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "procenv is null" << std::endl;
    }

    HANDLE child_write_pipe = NULL;  // child's STDOUT
    HANDLE parent_read_pipe = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { 0 };
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    // Create pipe to communicate with child.
    success = CreatePipe(&parent_read_pipe, &child_write_pipe, &sa, 0);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "CreatePipe fail" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    success = SetHandleInformation(parent_read_pipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "SetHandleInformation fail" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = child_write_pipe;
    si.hStdError = child_write_pipe;
    si.hStdInput = NULL;
    //// Prevent cmd window pop up.
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    WCHAR lpd[] = L"";
    si.lpDesktop = lpd;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Token must have TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY.
    success = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        NULL,   // app name
        cmd_line,    // includes app name.
        NULL,   // proc security attrs
        NULL,   // thread security attrs
        TRUE,   // inherit handles
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, // creation flags
        proc_env,    // env
        L"C:\\",   // current dir
        &si,    // startupinfo
        &pi);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateProcessAsUser() GLE " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the results from child (POLL / BLOCK).
    char* result_buf = NULL;
    _result_read(pi.hProcess, parent_read_pipe, &result_buf);
    if (result_buf)
    {
        std::cout << "result: " << result_buf << std::endl;
        // Copy into result object.
        free(result_buf);
    }

    // get exit code.
    DWORD ec = 0;
    success = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &ec);
    std::cout << "exit code: " << ec << std::endl;

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify C:\Windows\System32 as the working directory?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError of course this is not related. the `NtGdiInit` fails in conhost.exe . here real reason

Comment: To access the directory and executable image using the security context of the target user, specify hToken in a call to the `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function` before calling CreateProcessAsUser.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT - this is not need. impersonate another token need for got required provileges ( SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege ) and not need impersonate with user token (he not have SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege also). the src of error - another logon session, fail UI subsystem

Comment: @RbMm thanks for your help. I don't understand yet--what do you think I should do to fix my problem? I have given Administrators and my user SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege in Local Security Policy.

Comment: even if your account, for which you logon and start new process, will be built-in Administrator - no affected by UAC, process is started without errors, but UI.. it will be .. black window with strange caption). very not normal UI. i guess this is due another logon session. under debugger visible that NtGdiInit fail for not administrators. for admin not fail but ui not work anyway